# C segfault when assigning value to address in a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, embedded, segmentation-fault

I have a 2 structs like this

```
typedef struct data {
    int datap;
    int channelNumber;
} data;

typedef struct RingBuffer {
    unsigned int *size;
    unsigned int *start;
    unsigned int *count;
    unsigned int *end;
    data *elems;
} RingBuffer;
```

I am trying to initialize the ring buffer struct at a certain memory location (embedded application) with this:

```
void rbInit(RingBuffer *rb, unsigned int size) {
    //put rb into appropriate memory locations
    rb->size = (unsigned int *) (RB_UTILS_SIZE + USERSPACE_OFFSET);
    rb->start = (unsigned int *) (RB_UTILS_START + USERSPACE_OFFSET);
    rb->count = (unsigned int *) (RB_UTILS_COUNT + USERSPACE_OFFSET);
    rb->end = (unsigned int *) (RB_UTILS_END + USERSPACE_OFFSET);
    rb->elems = (data *) (RB_DATA + USERSPACE_OFFSET);

    //intialize rb parameter/pointer values
    data empty;
    empty.datap = 0;
    empty.channelNumber = 0;

    *(rb->size) = size; //SEGFAULT HERE
    *(rb->start) = 0;
    *(rb->count) = 0;
    *(rb->end) = 0; 
    *(rb->elems) = empty;
}
```

However, the code segfaults (see the comment in code). I've checked with gdb that rb->size is indeed pointing to the location where I want to put it and, yes, that location is available (shared ram on BeagleBone PRU). `RB_UTILS_SIZE`, `USERSPACE_OFFSET` and the likes are just hex addresses #defined elsewhere.

I am quite stoked as to what might be the problem.

Comment: Does it work if you try to assign that memory address directly?  e.g: *((unsigned int *)(RB_UTILS_SIZE + USERSPACE_OFFSET) = size;

Comment: It segfaults now in the main() on the line where I call rbInit() (I added your line of direct assignment as the 1st line in rbInit()). That would kind of imply that I can't write to that address. Although the control doesn't even enter rbInit(), it just segfaults in main. Also I've checked the memory maps in the TFM several times. In fact I've used that address before with success.

Comment: Can you please show us the actual values of your pointers, const, etc.. ?

Comment: You can not allocate `empty` on the stack.  Don't do that.

Comment: wow, what compiler are you using?  That seems like a pretty ugly API if you ask me.  I don't see why they didn't provide a function (even an inline) in a library that just returned a pointer to their struct. To me, that's just nasty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not specifically familiar with the BeagleBoard, but in Linux you cannot access RAM from a process without first getting access to it from the kernel.  Typically you would use mmap to get access to the memory, and the call would return a pointer to the memory for you to use in your application.  This may help:

[How to use shared memory with Linux in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656530/how-to-use-shared-memory-with-linux-in-c)

Is there a reason you're trying to use that specific address instead of just getting memory with malloc?

Comment: Long overdue, but to clarify for anyone reading this discussion: if I recall correctly, I was trying to access a particular bit in the processor which was shared between it's real-time unit and the main memory. I wanted to pipe some data to the userspace coming in from an SPI link and being real-time processed (in the PRU for those familiar with the BeagleBone and/or its processor) according to some maths relevant to the application.

Anyway, someone more involved with the project and more familiar with C and the hardware wrote a very neat solution and I moved to a different university.