# Linux shared memory: shmget() vs mmap()?

Tags: c, linux, posix, shared-memory, mmap

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656530/how-to-use-shared-memory-with-linux-in-c) thread the OP is suggested to use `mmap()` instead of `shmget()` to get shared memory in Linux.
I visited [this](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html) page and [this](http://www.jimscode.ca/index.php/component/content/article/13-c/45-c-simple-mmap-example) page to get some documentation, but the second one gives an obscure example regarding `mmap()`.

Being almost a newbie, and needing to share some information (in text form) between two processes, should I use the `shmget()` method or `mmap()`? And why?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Both methods are viable. `mmap` method is a little bit more restrictive then `shmget`, but easier to use. `shmget` is the old System V shared memory model and has the widest support. `mmap`/`shm_open` is the new POSIX way to do shared memory and is easier to use. If your OS permits the use of POSIX shared memory then I would suggest going with that.

Some hints:

- If you create your children via `fork` then `mmap` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED` is by far the easiest way - just one call. `MAP_ANONYMOUS` is however a Linux extension [not specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html).
- If you start the processes independently, but can supply them with a shared memory name then `shm_open` (+ `ftruncate`) + `mmap` with `MAP_SHARED` is two/three calls. Requires `librt` on some OSes.
- If your OS has `/dev/shm/` then `shm_open` is equivalent to opening a file in `/dev/shm/`.

Comment: Thank you for all the useful advices. I won't use fork for now.

Comment: But with mmap a file on the hard disk is authomatically modified when you modify the memory? So you cause frequent writings to that file?

Comment: `/dev/shm` is your RAMdisk. If you use file-backed shared memory `mmap` a file that is on an actual disk then it will be up to the OS to schedule updates. Normally the mapped file will not be updated until long after you stop using the mapping or the paging daemon decided to swap your pages out. You can force an update by calling `msync` which is the recommended practice when using file-backed mappings that you wish to write to disk.

Comment: @BowPark memory mapped with MAP_ANONYMOUS is NOT backed by a file.

Comment: On OSX you want mmap as the max shared memory with shmget is only 4mb across all processes sadly.

Comment: @GregoryRay you can use sysctl to change kern.sysv.shmmax and kern.sysv.shmall.

Answer (score 47):

A lot of this has to do with history and future directions.

Once upon a time there were two main (and somewhat competing) versions of unix - system V and BSD.  SysV had its own versions of IPC, including the big 3 - shared memory, semaphores, and message queues.  POSIX came along to try and unite things.

So at present we have two versions - posix shared memory, MQs, and semaphores and the sysV versions.  Just to make things a little more confusing the sysV versions are *also* part of posix.

So basically your question is do you want to use Posix or sysV style shared memory?  In general most people take the long term view and opt for Posix because that seems to be road to the future.  But, realistically, sysV stuff is so embedded in so many systems you have to have serious doubts that it will ever go away.

So, eliminating the long term stuff, it comes down to what makes sense for your project and your tastes.  In general the sysV versions tend to actually be somewhat more powerful but they have an clunky interface that most people find a little bewildering at first contact.  The is particularly true of sysV semaphores and message queues.  In terms of shared memory it can be argued both sysV and posix are awkward.  The sysV versions carries the clunky `ftok` and key stuff while the posix ends up taking multiple calls and some race conditions to set up.  From the outside, the posix versions have an advantage in that they utilize the file system and can be maintained with standard command line functions like 'rm' rather than relying on separate utility programs (e.g. `ipcs`) that sysV requires.

So which should you use?  As a rule, the posix versions.  But you should really familiarize yourself with sysV versions.  They have some features that go beyond the capabilities of the posix versions which you may want to take advantage of in specific situations.

Comment: Can you explain why you think the System V versions are more powerful?

Comment: Powerful might be the wrong word.  Fuller featured perhaps?  For instance sysv semaphores range from positive thru negatives numbers, can be added or subtracted, can undo an operation if a process dies, can report the last process to operate on them (that  would be more useful if that was extended to report threads), exist in kernel so you don't have to mess with shared memory, and you can create an entire set of them in one shot.  sysv MQs have msgtypes which allow many processes to easily share the same queue and just process a specific type. Posix MQs always read oldest msg w/i a priority