# c programming shmat ( ) permission denied

Tags: c, memory, shared-memory

I have a problem when I run my code. My shmat fails and prints permission denied. I searched on google how to solve it but I can't. My code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define ERROR -1

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    int shmid,key=50;
    int *val;
    int *x;
    int rw = -1;

    // 0 for write and 1 for read 

    shmid = shmget ( key, sizeof( int ), IPC_CREAT );

    if ( shmid == -1 ) {
        perror ( "Error in shmget\n" );
        return ( ERROR );
    }

    val = ( int * ) shmat ( shmid, NULL, 0 );

    if ( val == -1 ) {
        perror ( "Error in shmat\n" );
        return ( ERROR );
    }

    scanf ( "%d", &rw);

    while ( rw >= 0 ) {
        if ( rw == 0 ) {
            //write in the shared memory
            x = ( int * ) malloc ( sizeof ( int ) );

            if ( x == NULL ) {
                perror ( "Error in malloc" );
                return ( ERROR );
            }

            scanf ( "%d", x );

            val = x;

        }
        else {
            // read from the shared memory
            if ( rw == 1 ) {
                printf ( "%d\n", *val );
            }
        }

        scanf ( "%d", &rw );
    }

    return ( 0 );

}
```

In this code I want to test the shared memory. I write an integer in the shared memory when I give rw = 1 else I read the value of the shared memory and then I print this value. I can't find where is the problem....

Comment: 1) when calling scanf(), and family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameters) to assure the operation was successful.  2) in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc(), and family of functions.

Comment: when running the posted code, the user has no indication that the only valid input values are 1 and 0.  All the user sees is a prompt.   Also, were the user to enter only a newline, the posted code will try to process what ever trash happens to be in memory at the '*x' variable.

Comment: every time the user enters a 0, another malloc is performed, overlaying the prior malloc pointer (which results in a memory leak)   I.E. every time a malloc is to be performed, except the first time, the prior allocated memory pointer needs to be passed to free().   Note: if 'x' is initialized to NULL, then can always pass 'x' to free()

Comment: 'val' points to the shared memory.  overlaying that pointer with what ever is in 'x' results in a memory leak.  the shared memory needs to be detached/destroyed before returning.  the final call to free(x) needs to be performed before the return statement.

Comment: when compiling, all the warnings need to be enabled, then you would see (at least) two warnings. 1) unused parameter 'argc'  2) unused parameter 'argv[]'

Comment: the thing to google for would be: 'example of using shared memory in C'  which brings up many 'hits'.  suggest <http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~iq/csc209s/smalllectures/csc209_w10_4.pdf> as an excellent example

Answer (score 7):

You created the shared memory segment with permissions set to `0000`:

```
shmid = shmget ( key, sizeof( int ), IPC_CREAT );
```

should be

```
shmid = shmget ( key, sizeof( int ), IPC_CREAT | 0660 );
```

or similar.

Comment: It has problem too. I tried that. My problem is in shmat

Comment: it is always a good idea to read the manual (man page) for any system function that your code is using.

Comment: @ΧρήστοςΓεωργακίδης - The shared memory segment still exists with 0000 permissions.  What does `ipcs -q` show?  If it's still there, you can use `ipcrm` to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You also have a mistake here:

```
val = x;
```

should be:

```
*val = *x;
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a serious error.  Even if you solve the permissions problem, you'll have a head scratcher why the memory is not being shared.

Answer (score 1):

besides the problem with the shmget() call, as described in another answer

And the numerous problems with the code that reads/writes some integer

the fact that the OP is still getting a 'permission denied' message is because the shared memory has

```
1) not been detached -- see the man page for shmdt()
2) not been destroyed -- see the man page for shmctl()
```

Fix those two problem and the shared memory operations will work nicely.

However, as mentioned in the comments, there are lots of other problems with the posted code