# Segmentation fault when get an array form shared memory

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, shared-memory

I want to share an array in shared memory but i can't fill it cause give me back segmentation fault and i have no idea why.This is the first time with shared memory so i don't know how to use it for my purpose.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int *array;
    int shmid;
    shmid = shmget(1234,3*sizeof(int),IPC_CREAT);
    if(shmid == -1) {
        perror("shmget error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    array = (int*)shmat(shmid,NULL,0);
    int array_copy[3];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        array_copy[i] = i;
        memcpy( &array[i], &array_copy[i], sizeof(int) );
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf("\n nm: %d and array: %d",array_copy[i],array[i]);
    shmdt((void *) array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the return value of `shmat`. I think you will find it is failing. Call `perror` on failure to get a more specific error description.

Comment: Why call `memcpy` and not just `array[i] = array_copy[i];`?

Comment: ok. i'm checking the value of shamt and i found the error in the answer below

Comment: i use memcpy cause i thought that  array[i] = array_copy[i]; maybe was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not checking the result of `shmat()`.  On my system it fails and `perror()` says "Permission denied".  So you can look for answers here: [c programming shmat ( ) permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199805/c-programming-shmat-permission-denied)

Comment: Thanks, was an error of permission, I solved added | 0666 to shmget. But how this number are chosen? The man pages don't do anything or i didn't see.

Comment: 0666 here has the same meaning as in Unix file permissions.  0 means it's an octal number, and 6 means read+write access.  Three 6's means read+write for the original user, their group, and everyone else.  You may want stricter permissions such as 0660 or 0600.