# Create shared memory segments in kernel space?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, system

I'm trying to create a "mailbox" system call where processes can send messages to each other. I wanted to use some sort of shared memory so I can refer to a "mailbox" by its ID, but I can't call system calls from another system call right? Is there another way where I can "refer" to a particular "mailbox" by its ID? I was thinking of just using `kmalloc` and creating an array of structs. Not looking for code, just general pointers as to how I should do this. Thank you!

EDIT: Don't think I clarified but the mailboxes have to be in kernel space

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can't call `kmalloc` from userspace.

What you're looking for is actually called POSIX "shared memory".

In general, you call [`shm_open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) to open a shared memory object. Then you [`mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) it, so you can access it via a pointer, just like normal memory.

See also:

- [How to use shared memory with Linux in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656530/how-to-use-shared-memory-with-linux-in-c)
- [`shm_overview(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)
- [IPC: Shared Memory](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html) (includes example code)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the "mailboxes" have to be in kernel space

Comment: @user1813076 I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish, that you can't with features that already exist. You have lots of IPC mechanisms at your disposal: UNIX sockets (including file-based), pipes, shared memory. What features do these mailboxes possess that aren't satisfied by those means?  Note that the actual memory where a UNIX socket's buffers live is in kernel space.

Comment: It's just for a project in my operating systems class. We have to create something similar to shared  memory segments

Comment: So you're planning on modifying the Linux kernel? I think adding a system call to create or use these mailboxes would make sense then.