# Sharing memory between processes (C, linux) using shm_lock, shm_unlock, ipc_stat, ipc_set, ipc_rmid

Tags: c, linux, ipc, shared-memory

there's this problem i am working with but since i am a bit new on linux and also programming in C, it would be a great help improving my skills if somebody could help me with this problem.

I'm practicing using `Linux`, so i got into this problem after I was studying about it and it got stuck into my mind since i can't barely find a solution.

**The problem was:** Creating a program for process communication (`client-server`) using `Shared Memory`, and also use *shm_lock, shm_unlock, ipc_stat, ipc_set, ipc_rmid*

I only know the client-server communication, by that i mean that te server sending a string to the clinet and the client letting him know that it got the message.

I really hope somebody helps me or redirects me to some page where i can find or read more about this problem/solution.

THANKS!

Comment: This is a bit too general. Please try to code something yourself and ask again (providing this code) if it doesn't work.For a primer: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node21.html

Comment: You can read more in your terminal, actually, by typing `man shm_lock`

Comment: @Ctx - the thing is i just need to write that program using those properties, so that two processes can communicate using shared memory (client-server)

Comment: So do it! What is your actual problem? `shmget()` creates shared memory and returns its *id*. `shmat()` attaches the shared memory segment to the address space of the calling process and returns segment's start address. `shmdt()` detaches shared memory. If you have still problem, you can refer to this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656530/how-to-use-shared-memory-with-linux-in-c) (see [linked examples](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html)).

Comment: @patryk.beza , thanks a lot mate, u kinda motivated me! I would like to keep in touch, any email or somewhere I can contact you?! Or I simply share my facebook account link? (ps. this ain't my real name haha)