# How to delete the key created by the ftok() function

Tags: c, linux, ipc, shared-memory, ftok

```
int main(void) {
    key_t key = ftok("/sys/ipc", 0);
    int shmid = shmget(key, 1024, IPC_CREATE | 0x0604);
}
```

when I run this code second time, because the key collision so the value of `shmid` is `-1`

How can I delete the key I set before?

Comment: What's the value of `key` after the call to `ftok`?

Comment: 16842754, this one..

Comment: Maybe [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656530/how-to-use-shared-memory-with-linux-in-c) helps.