# Passing reference to a c executable

Tags: c, parameter-passing

Is it possible to send a reference to a variable as a parameter to an executable in C?

Suppose I have a parent process called `main` which has multiple arrays defined. Now, if I `fork()` and `exec*()` a C program called `sort` per array. My questions are: can I create a `sort` program which can access by reference an array (defined in `main`)? How can I pass the reference to an array from `main`?

The advantage that I see in this implementation is the simplicity that I get as the parent process passes the reference to the array, and once the `sort` has exited properly, the array will be sorted. (Given, I must write and use the program `sort`.)

Comment: Separate processes cannot readily share data — you'd have to use shared memory.  So the whole basis of your question is not directly feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot. Once a process is executed with a `exec*()` function, it has no more access to the old process's variables.

> *man execlp*
>
> The  `exec()`  family  of  functions **replaces** the current process image with a new process image.

You can pass to the `exec`d program values through the `argv` array of
arguments. If that's not possible because you have complex data structures, then
you can use shared memory between your programs. See [How to use shared memory with Linux in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656530/how-to-use-shared-memory-with-linux-in-c)