# Segmentation fault after assigning an pointer to a specific memory address and changing its value

Tags: c++, linux, pointers, memory, segmentation-fault

Ok, 
I have a working program that reads external virtual memory on linux.
This is what I want to do:
Program 1 is executed and has specific addresses in memory to communicate with program 2.
I know that program 2, which is reading and writing values to and from program 1 is working
I am stuck with the making of program 2, I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int* i;
  i = (int*)0x7ffABCDDCBA1;
  *i = 1;
  cout << *i << " " << i << endl;
}
```

Note:

this is just a test code to see if it works(it doesn't)

program1 would read 0x7ffABCDDCBA1 at program 2's pid,
it compiles just fine, but on executing i get "Segmentation fault"

Note:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int* i;
  i = (int*)0x7ffABCDDCBA1;
  cout << i << endl;
}
```

Works just fine

Comment: you should know the difference between *i and i. you may be dereferencing invalid memory address in first code

Comment: Memory addresses in one process have no meaning in another process.  That's what virtual addressing is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing some random memory location, which most likely does not belong to your process address space and so causes undefined behavior.

You should use shared memory between processes: [How to use shared memory in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656530/how-to-use-shared-memory-with-linux-in-c).

There are few other techniques, but this one is most comonnly used for this purpose.

Comment: You're right about that, but i wonder if i could do it this way, this project is just for fun so if there'd be a way to do it like this it'd be nice

Comment: Yes it _might_ work, but as I said - it has Undefined behavior. Thats the reason why it sometimes works, and sometimes do not.

Comment: No problem, i would recommend you some linux address space related article. Its fun reading