# Is there a way to share a data structure between two C programs in the same shell?

Tags: c, bash, shell, share

I have defined a stack, here is part of its definition in the header file:

```c
typedef struct item {
    char *path;
    struct item *below;
} item_t;

struct forward_dir_stack {
    int _curr_size;
    item_t *top;
};

struct forward_dir_stack *create();
void push(struct forward_dir_stack *stack, char *path);
item_t *pop(struct forward_dir_stack *stack);
...
```

and I have two C programs `foo.c` and `boo.c`. Let's say that `boo.c` pushes something to the stack and `foo.c` pops something out of the stack.

I want to compile these two programs (and move them to `/bin`) and use them as two separated bash commands.

```sh
$ boo  # pushes something in stack (in the same terminal)
$ foo  # pops something from the stack (in the same terminal)
```

My goal is to get these two programs to share `forward_dir_stack` with each other in the same terminal they are running. (and of course, when new terminal is opened, another separate stack will be created and `boo` `foo` running in this terminal will work with this stack)

First idea that comes to my mind is to create a temporary file which will contain shell PID in the name so `boo` or `foo` will know where to push/pop. (also this means I have to re-implement the stack)

But isn't there more elegant/easy way how to share data structure between C programs in the same shell (and behave independently when running in another shell)? Somehow take advantage of the fact that `foo` and `boo` run in the same shell.

Comment: Inter process communication?

Comment: Your idea of using PPID in the name is good. Instead of a file use shared memory. see, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/q/5656530/1216776

Comment: maybe just `boo | foo` ?

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem. Also: you cannot do this without some locking mechanism.

Comment: What should happen if more `foo`'s and `boo`'s are started in the same terminal?