# Pointer-like functionality in IPC

Tags: c++, boost, ipc, boost-interprocess

I have been working for a while with interprocess communication using Boost and have managed to pass big amounts of data between multiple processes/executables in POSIX. When reading from the shared memory i simply use `memcpy`. However, one chunk of data is especially big (~30MB) and time-critical which makes passing data using `memcpy` problematic.

The goal here is to be able to pass the 30MB chunk of data from process 1 to process 2 without having to move memory, but rather having process 2 access it immediately using some sort of pointer-like behaviour. The problem I am facing here, of course, is the "limitations" of the address space.

Reading online I found that Boost offers `offset_ptr`, but I am unsure of if this is the right way to go.

Could someone shed some light on this problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could use the SystemV IPC shared memory for that. Then the first process only have to send a `GO` to the second process and both have access to the same shared memory. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5656530/3684343 is for C, but the API can be used in C++ too (just don't send objects).

Comment: @mch Thank you! Does this work for different executables as well?

Comment: Yes, it is Inter Process Communication. :) The `mmap` as it is in the first answer works only with `fork`ed processes. If you have 2 executables, you have to specify the same file in both executables and make the file at least as big as the shared memory.

Comment: If you're already using shared memory, why can't process 2 directly access the shared memory? why does it need to use memcpy?

Comment: Your question is too broad for me to answer. However, I have *many* existing answers that show precisely how to do this in many situations varying from very simple to very advanced (using complicated allocator-aware datastructures). Just search my answers for inspiration: [managed_shared_memory](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20managed_shared_memory), [managed_mapped_file](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20managed_mapped_file), [mapped_region](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20mapped_region)

Comment: @user253751 because directly accessing it by, for example, using `mapped_region::get_address()` from process 2 throws `Bus Error` since the address is in another memory space. This is as far as my understanding goes, however. Is perhaps `mmap` ing the address in process 2 a workaround?

Comment: @sehe I have decided to work with UNIX instead. Working with `shm_open` along with `mmap` seems to be best documented and used for situations such as this. I can add that I need to share `v4l2_buffer`s from one process to another and be able to directly reference the data from both ends. Using anonymous mapping wrapped in `shm_open` seems like a proper way, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @CarlWikström stop thinking about objects, start thinking about memory addresses. What is the program doing that causes it to throw `Bus Error`?

Comment: @user253751 From what I read here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.mapped_region.mapped_region_address_mapping 
Addresses cannot be used since the two processes do not map the same memory to the same address space. This invalidates the use of pointers

Comment: Yes but I'm asking what your program is doing, not how shared memory works.

Comment: @user253751 The two processes open up a `shared_memory_object` with the same name. They then map it using `mapped_region`s in the same way. Process 1 copies some data to one of the regions, and when process 2 tries to read from that `mapped_region` using pointers ( `mapped_region::get_address()` ) and dereferencing it throws `Bus Error`.

Comment: What is the data? What data type?

Comment: @user253751 I don't see the relevance, I use it as a `void *` and hard reading from it by e.g. `unsigned int i = &(int *)mem` throws.

Comment: `&(int *)mem` makes no sense. If you did `*(int*)region.get_address()` this should not throw as long as the memory is mapped. What is `region.get_size()`?

Comment: @user253751 You're right, i meant `*(int *)mem` of course, just me being sloppy in the answer. This throws as well, although I will go back and double check but last I tried doing this it throwed.

Comment: And also shared_memory.get_size

Comment: @user253751 You were right, it works simply using the pointer directly. It feels odd, but I guess my understanding of address spaces in different processes is still very limited. Thanks for being stubborn! :)

Comment: @CarlWikström What does "simply using the pointer directly" mean, and how is it different to what you were doing before?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249806/discussion-between-carl-wikstrom-and-user253751).